# can't find mongodb collections/data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm working on a web app with node/express/mongodb, using mongoose. I created a folder in my project called `data` and inside I created another folder called `db`

- data

  - db

when I start mongo, I use the `--dbpath` parameter and point it to my project `data` folder that I created. It connects fine and everything. I've been writing some data to the database, and the application loads it correctly, but I can't find the data when I open mongo shell.

first thing is, when I open shell the only database I get is `test`. Is this auto created if I don't specify a database name? how do I specify a database name? I have the following in my `app.js` file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/abduldb');
```

My guess is that a database named `abduldb` should be created correct? I don't see this in mongo shell.

Also, when using the `test` database, I run `show collections` and it shows no results... Where exactly is my data being written? I only have 1 model right now and it looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String
});

mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);
```

and I'm adding new items in my route file using:

```
router.post('/items', function (req, res, next) {
  var item = new Item(req.body);
  item.save(function(err, item){
    if(err){ return next(err); }
    res.json(item);
  });
});
```

Comment: When you run the mongo shell, try "use abduldb". Also check to see if more than one mongo instance is running.

Comment: ok trying that now, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @BrettMcLain strange, that worked, I was able to connect to the database but when I run `db` in shell it only shows `test`. Why is that? I also downloaded `robomongo` and after connecting, it doesn't show the database either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in the mongo shell, try this command: "use abduldb".

The reason you don't see your collections is because you are automatically connected to the test db. If you want to change that, run this when you start mongo shell:

```
mongo abduldb
```

Alternatively, you can change the default db in your [.mongorc.js](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-mongorc-file) file by adding/changing this line:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("abduldb")
```

The .mongorc.js file can be found at /etc/mongorc.js, but is overridden if it exists in your home directory (i.e. /home/abduldb/.mongorc.js).

Comment: `db = db.getSiblingDB('mydb')` I have to replace 'mydb' with my database name right?

Comment: cool thanks for the help! wheres the .mongorc.js file by the way, I can't find it in my mongo installation directory

Comment: @duxfox It should be in your home folder. I recommend this: https://github.com/aheckmann/mongorc.js

`git clone https://github.com/aheckmann/mongorc.js`
`cd mongorc.js`
`make install`